# Magento 2.0 - How to add jquery on click to a button or link a JS file in System.xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I need a button in my custom system.xml to do Ajax call.  How can this be achieved? or how can I link a JS file into my system.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `frontend_model` will be your friend to achieve your requirement.

Just look at Validate VAT Number example from store > configuration > general > Store Information.

In this example magento using below `frontend_model`

```
<frontend_model>Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Validatevat</frontend_model>
```

Just look at this file, you will definitely get the idea how to achieve this.

Comment: The sample Validatevat you suggested has the thing I need.  Its working now.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you @Rahahaha

Comment: One more thing, how do we include JS files in the system.xml config?<link src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&libraries=geometry,places" />
            <link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.22/gmaps.min.js" />
            <link src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Geolocation/1.0.50/jquery.geolocation.min.js" />